# Should I write logic for visuals clientside and serverside when using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I was wondering how on Facebook, you would go from this:

[image]

To this (on the clientside):

[image]

But also if you were to refresh the page it would say:

[image]

Does this mean that Facebook have logic on both the front and backend to display this information like this?

Or would the logic only exist on the front end, and the server is simply informing the client of what users 'liked' the post? The reason I am asking is because I am trying to achieve something similar with this:

[image]

I need it to update the counter on the buttons and also colour them accordingly based on your selection, however, I am about to 'repeat' the visual logic both serverside and clientside which doesn't seem practical..

How would you approach colouring these buttons, should I do so with PHP or should I just pass a bunch of information and let the clientside scripting decide?

Comment: It *would* be practical to have this logic on both sides if you are looking for the functionality you describe :)

Comment: You could also just have it on the serverside and re-render the component (from the server) when the data changes.

Comment: It is not possible to simply do this client side, a flag of some sort is required. You will need to check for whether the current user has added a thumb up/down on the server side.  This can be an additional parameter/flag to the display code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will set the appropriate "Like" display on the front end and send a message to the backend that it was clicked. It is a game of data, where as long as you can keep the two ends consistent, you don't need to reload anything, store anything in cookies, etc. In fact storing anything permanently on the client side is not beneficial, because if I move machines, suddenly I no longer get the "You liked something" sign.

The way Facebook and similar websites do this effect, is they check if you are one of the people who likes the post. This happens on the backend. So for instance you might get a JSON string from the backend like this (please let me know if I got the JSON string wrong in terms for formatting):

```
   { 'Posts':
          { 
               'Title': 'Foos are cool!', 
               'Content' : 'They totally are, don\'t even argue!',
               'youLike' : 1,
               'likeCount' : 10
           }
   }
```

where the `youLike: 1` indicates that you do "liked" the post at some time before loading the page. When you click the "like" or "unlike" button, the JavaScript on the front end makes the appropriate HTML changes to reflect the data. Then it informs the backend of the event. Let's say you unlike something, but you haven't reloaded the page. When you press "unlike" button (or whatever it is these days), the javascript will make the appropriate changes to the front end and then send a signal to the backend. A signal might look like this:

```
  { 'Action' : 'Like', 'Value' : 0, 'PostID' : 123534234, 'UserID' : 1234234 }
```

which informs the backend that the value on the front end is now 0, or false. So the backend can now interpret this as "The like value was set to 0" and make the appropriate changes.

So when you reload the page, you now get `youLike: 0` instead of the previous `youLike: 1`

I hope that KIND of answers your question. If you need me to clarify anything, please let me know!

Comment: this is some useful information, and answers the question completely. +1